# Is my limit proof ok? , with $f(x)^2$

Tags: limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

Thank you for your time!

I would like to check if my proof is ok here:

Prove: Let $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)= 4$. Prove that for every $M>0, x>M$, $15.5 < [f(x)]^2 < 16.5$.

So, I said that: $-\sqrt{15.5} < f(x) < \sqrt{16.5}$

$ |f(x)-L| < \epsilon$,

I chose $\epsilon = 0.05$, and than $-0.05 < f(x)-4 < 0.05$

From here, $3.95 < f(x) < 4.05$ and $15.6025 < [f(x)]^2 < 16.4025$

So $15.5 < [f(x)]^2 < 16.5$

Is that legit?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  This would be easier to read with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  I took the liberty of changing some tags

Comment: Edited to use MathJax.

Comment: Not clear. It seems to me that you misunderstood the definition. I don't think it is correct to say "for every $M$...". It should be for every $\epsilon >0$, there exists an $M>0$ ...

Comment: This is the question... Thank you Tanner for helping me with MathJax!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the question should read, prove that if $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 4$ then there *exists* a number $M$ such that for all $x > M$,
$$15.5 < f(x)^2 < 16.5.$$

With this understanding, by definition of the concept of limit, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $M$ (dependent on $\varepsilon$) such that when $x > M$, $|f(x) - 4| < \varepsilon$.  That means,
$$ 4-\varepsilon < f(x) < 4 + \varepsilon.$$
Now you can square the inequality provided all terms are positive;  that will be the case if $\varepsilon$ is small enough, and so,
$$16 - 8 \varepsilon + \varepsilon^2 < f(x)^2 < 16 + 8 \varepsilon + \varepsilon^2.$$
Now just choose $\varepsilon$ so small that the left extreme is greater than $15.5$ and the right extreme is less than $16.5$.  For example $\varepsilon = 0.01$.  Then with the corresponding $M$ the required statement is true.

Of course you can get many different values for $M$ but your are only asked to show one exists.  Once you have on, any larger $M$ would also work.  Some smaller $M$ might also work depending on how finely you chose the first one.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will definitely try out this way!
The question indeed says that there exists an M>0 such that for every x>M, we have the statement. So yes, I do need to find an epsilon in this case. Thanks again!